# Virtual Box: Add Host Only Adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I try to create the network first in file-> preferences.

I get the error:

Failed to create the host network interface.

```
VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: HostNetworkInterfaceWrap
Interface: IHostNetworkInterface {455f8c45-44a0-a470-ba20-27890b96dba9}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be related with current VirtualBox Version 5.0.16, I had the same issue, installed Version 5.0.14 from Ubuntu package archive and it worked for me.

Comment: More exactly: Using 5.0.14 instead of 5.0.16 solved the issue

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)